# SQL sub query. Dont know how to start

Tags: sql, oracle

The table is called `PEOPLE` and has the columns: id, fname, lname, state, jobtitle, salary, cat

I want to display the 50 states, the number of people in the state with a Cat value of Y, the number of people in the state with a Cat value of N and the total number of people in the state. The four column headings should be State, Yes, No and Total.

I know that we are supposed to use sub queries but not sure how to begin.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS sub`. the `...` are left as an exercise to OP.

Comment: Please read [ask] to get an idea of things you should provide in your question to get better answers, and not get down-voted.

Comment: You got your answer, but...  more questions for you. First, is it guaranteed that the Cat column only has the values Y and N, and there are no NULL "values"? Second, in case there are NO people in a state in your table, do you still want the state to show in your output, with counts of 0 for Yes, No and Total? (The answers you received ignore both questions - is that OK for your situation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
SELECT upper(p.state) State,
     (SELECT count(*) from PEOPLE p2 where p2.state = p.state and p2.cat = 'Y') Yes,
     (SELECT count(*) from PEOPLE p3 where p3.state = p.state and p3.cat = 'N') No,
     count(*) Total
FROM PEOPLE p
GROUP BY upper(state)
```

If you have any doubt about it, fell free to ask.

Comment: his code does seem to work but i have a messy data. for example TX AND tx are 2 different states. therefore i am getting different answers. also i am getting a total of 121 states when it shouldn't be more than 50. can you please help me with this. thank you so much in advance

Comment: Just use upper (or lower) function. Edited the answer.

Comment: I DID IT. IT WORKS but for some reason yes and no are not adding up to total.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it :)

Comment: If it was useful to you don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: The other answer was a bit better. (No need for sub-queries.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT State
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Cat = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Cat = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) No
     , COUNT(*) as Total
  FROM PEOPLE
 GROUP BY STATE
```

Comment: this code does seem to work but i have a messy data. for example TX AND tx are 2 different states. therefore i am getting different answers. also i am getting a total of 121 states when it shouldn't be more than 50. can you please help me with this. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to clean up your state information somehow.  In your example of "TX" and "tx" you could convert them both to the same case.  In the query I wrote you'd change `State` to `UPPER(State) State`.  However, if you're getting 121 values then you probably have invalid state abbreviations for the US.  How to clean up state abbreviations seems like a separate question to me.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted answer.  If there is an issue with messy data, it is not mentioned in the question.  However, it is trivial to use `upper()` or `lower()` to fix the casing of `state`.  Using subqueries for the final result is way over-complicated.

Comment: @Kateract, that's case expressions! (Not case statements...)